# Solr - writing custom request handler

Tags: solr, lucene

Is there any good tutorial online that explains how to write a custom request handler?

I googled and googled and didn't find anything.

Thanks

Comment: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPlugins#SolrRequestHandler || http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRequestHandler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the example @ [link](http://sujitpal.blogspot.in/2011/02/solr-custom-search-requesthandler.html).
Also you can always refer to the Current Solr source code for existing request handler and have it implemented in similar way